# Generating UUID instead of default ObjectId for MongoDB docuemnts with typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, typeorm

how to use UUIDs instead of the default ObjectIds for mongodb models in typeorm and nodejs. I tried this solution but no luck:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryColumn,
  Column
} from "typeorm";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

@Entity("ChargingPoint")
export class Sample {
  @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
  id!: string;

  //rest of columns

  constructor(){
    this.id = uuidv4();
  }
}
```

Comment: The automatically generated field is `_id`, not `id`

Comment: @Asma Gheisari   :   Please edit your question to indicate exactly what you mean by 'no luck."   Was an error generated?   Did (as Wernfried suggests) a new field `_id` pop up instead your intended `id`?

Comment: @Asma, did you find a solution for this issue? The error I am getting with your code is ```MongoEntityManager.ts:182     $in: ids.map((id) => {    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'propertyName')```. I'm using nestjs v10.0.2, typeorm v0.3.20, and mongodb v6.3.0